# Is there a way to exclude certain apps from showing in the spotlight/alfred results

Tags: spotlight, alfred

I mainly use Alfred to launch various apps and I am kind of annoyed when I am trying to open chrome, the chess app is the first in the results and fibre channel comes up first when I am trying to open Firefox. Unfortunately it seems like I can not add specific apps to be excluded in the spotlight preferences so that chess.app and fibrechannel.prefpane are not shown in the spotlight results. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you go to **System Preferences** > **Spotlight** > **Privacy** and click the [+] button to add an *application* they are grayed out and cannot be added in this method.

However, you can, instead of clicking the [+] button, simply drag and drop the *application(s)* from **Finder** onto the *list area* of the **Privacy** *tab* to have it removed from **Spotlight** searches.

Comment: It works! Now it isn't possible to add a single app using plus button, I added Terminal.app using drag-and-drop, then cleared app cache in Albert.